# Efficient sparse matrix column change

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm implementing an efficient PageRank algorithm so I'm using sparse matrices. I'm close, but there's one problem. I have a matrix where I want the sum of each column to be one. This is easy to implement, but the problem occurs when I get a matrix with a zero column.

In this case, I want to set each element in the column to be 1/(n-1) where n is the dimension of the matrix. I divide by n-1 and not n because I wish to keep the diagonals zero, always.

How can I implement this efficiently? My naive solution is to just determine the sum of each column and then find the column indices that are zero and replace the entire column with an 1/(n-1) value like so:

```
# naive approach (too slow!)
# M is my nxn sparse matrix where each column sums to one
col_sums = M.sum(axis=0)
for i in range(n):
   if col_sums[0,i] == 0:
      # set entire column to 1/(n-1)
      M[:, i] = 1/(n-1)
      # make sure diagonal is zeroed
      M[i,i] = 0
```

My M matrix is very very *very* large and this method simply doesn't scale. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Using a `csc` formatted matrix might be better than a `csr`.  Or take the transpose (so you are working with rows), and possibly convert to `lil` format while setting the rows.  Another idea is to try to set all of the `0` columns at once, at least the `1/n-1` values.  Adding the non-zero values is the most expensive step since it changes sparsity.  Simply scaling existing nonzeros relatively cheap.

Comment: Try setting the values in one go, like compute the zero columns with cols = np.where(col_sums==0)[0], then do assignment like M[:,cols] = 1/(n-1). Then do another assignment round where you turn all the diagonals zero. You can perhaps access the diagonals with M[np.arange(n),np.arange(n)], or with np.diag_indices(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add new nonzero values without reallocating and copying the underlying data structure. If you expect these zero columns to be very common (> 25% of the data) you should handle them in some other way, or you're better off with a dense array.

Otherwise try this:

```
import scipy.sparse

M = scipy.sparse.rand(1000, 1000, density=0.001, format='csr')

nz_col_weights = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(M.shape, dtype=M.dtype)
nz_col_weights[:, M.getnnz(axis=0) == 0] = 1 / (M.shape[0] - 1)
nz_col_weights.setdiag(0)

M += nz_col_weights
```

This has only two allocation operations

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful, but it ultimately did not work because it was too expensive allocating a new sparse matrix and then modifying its sparsity.

Comment: This uses the same amount of memory as the loop and is a solution to Y. What you should be doing is solving X - adding a billion copies of the same number to a sparse matrix is a mistake. Alter your (regression? ml?) to assume uniform weights in zero columns instead.